# Can JavaScript be used to prefetch external CSS and JS files, ready for the next page on same website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, browser-cache

I am in the process of optimising a website, with the main aim of improving the overall download times of web pages. I have been applying as many of the techniques recommended by the Yahoo Developer Network's ["Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site"](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).

Now, the stats show that we have a lot of visitors that first access the website via:

the stand-alone search engine page
HTTP error handlers - i.e. our custom "404 Not Found” page
other miscellaneous stand-alone pages

Please note that these so-called "stand-alone pages” exist independently from the template system which is responsible for the layout and structure of the pages from the website proper. They have their own style sheet(s) and scripts (and therefore exist independently of the template system's CSS and JS files also).

Now, these page types are more intermediary pages than content pages. A good example of their general purpose would be that of a [reference landing page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landing_page#Reference_landing_page). I thought that it would be a good idea to use a technique like  **post-onload** to “prime” the user's cache ready for their next move (which will nearly *always* be part of the main template system).

The script by Steve Sounders is:

**[post-onload.php](http://stevesouders.com/examples/post-onload.php):**

```
<script>
function doOnload() {
    // Do the downloading awhile AFTER the onload.
    setTimeout("downloadComponents()", 1000);
}

window.onload = doOnload;

// Download external components dynamically using JavaScript.
function downloadComponents() {
    downloadCSS("http://stevesouders.com/hpws/testsm.css?t=1388138263");
    downloadJS("http://stevesouders.com/hpws/testsma.js?t=1388138263");
    downloadJS("http://stevesouders.com/hpws/testsmb.js?t=1388138263");
    downloadJS("http://stevesouders.com/hpws/testsmc.js?t=1388138263");
}

// Download a stylesheet dynamically.
function downloadCSS(url) {
    var elem = document.createElement("link");
    elem.rel = "stylesheet";
    elem.type = "text/css";
    elem.href = url;
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
}

// Download a script dynamically.
function downloadJS(url) {
    var elem = document.createElement("script");
    elem.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
</script>
```

What I would like to know is this:

**Is it possible to re-write the two functions that perform basically the same thing as `downloadCSS(url)`  and `downloadJS(url)`, __without__ it actually being applied to the containing web page?**

In effect, I am looking for `downloadCSS(url)` / `downloadJS(url)` functions that acts as a pre-load for the next web page's external CSS/JS files, which will behave 
much like the way the HTML5 spec intends the `@prefetch` attribute to be implemented). I basically want the files downloaded via **post-onload** to be in the cache ready.

If not, any other suggestions on how to perform the same task would be amazing!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suppose, On a single page you have 20 links of another pages. Now ,how would you come to know **which link** is going to be your _next page_?

Comment: So basically, load a lot more css that isn't needed on the current page at all, just so it's cached on the next page, makes sense?

Comment: A good question, HI2 – because the other 20 pages will invariably use the same template system, and therefore require the same CSS/JavaScript files and presentational images. I just though that, seeing as the site-search page is light-weight anyway, then may be a good time to get them into the cache “in the background,” as the other pages are a bit heavier than the one mentioned.

Comment: PS: I thought that the practice was quite common in broader a sense, e.g. I’ve heard of web apps that have a really lightweight login page as their default home page for new or logged-out users, and “prime” the cache at this point. This will help spread the weight and the wait, i.e. make the initial loading time of the start page (and all other pages within) more faster overall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you using `?t=1388138263` you cannot preload at all, because every time you will load a new version..

with jquery you can do something like:

```
$.ajax('script.js',{cache: true, dataType:'script'});
//or
$.getScript('script.js')
$.ajax('styles.css',{cache: true});
```

or you can create invisible iframe and load in to it html page which load all js and css files

hope this help